# Multiple value Search in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

Here is my code

```
$search_term = "Hary Kumar";
$filterData = DB::table('signups')->where('name','LIKE',"%{$search_term}%");
```

If I am not wrong above code will give me result like:

```
select * from signups where name like "%Hary Kumar%"
```

But, I am trying to get

```
select * from signups where name like "%Hary%" or name like "%Kumar%"
```

Comment: Why are you want to do like these?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a simple [orWhere()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#or-where-clauses)

```
DB::table('signups')
    ->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$first_term}%")
    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%{$second_term}%");
```

Answer (score -1):

I got my answer. Here is the code:

```
$search_values = explode(" ",$search_term);

 DB::table('signups')
    ->orWhere(function ($query) use($search_values) {
    foreach($search_values as $search_value)
    $query->orwhere('name', 'like',  '%' . $search_value .'%');})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).